# How can I get the line in input signal and measure frequencies? (C++)

Tags: c++, c, audio, windows-7

Can I get live signal from line in using C++ to measure frequencies of the input? Maybe there are some libraries or winapi programming techniques to achieve that? 

I want to get the frequency of each note from my electric guitar which I have plugged into the sound card input using 3.5mm jack(converter).

 Sorry for making it confusing.

Platform: Windows 7 or Ubuntu with gnome 3 shell.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here. What kind of input do you want exactly?

Comment: "live signal from line" ? What is that supposed to mean ? Be mor eexplicit. Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Look for a math library that includes FFT. Getting the signal into the code, that depends on the A/D hardware you have access to.

Comment: "from line in", probably meaning sound card line input. But needs more information.